# OpenVPN clients unable to connect to internet

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm having some issue getting clients to connect to the internet. It can connect to the internal network, but not the internet. Anyone know what might be wrong? Here are my iptables for the OpenVPN server:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 53189 packets, 70M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
2      137 16324 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere
3     4841  586K ACCEPT     udp  --  wlan0  any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 256 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2     4274  270K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  tun0    anywhere             anywhere
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   wlan0   anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 13229 packets, 1247K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


$ sudo iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 122 packets, 19337 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 583 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 1386 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 1386 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2621  166K SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.8.0.0/24         !10.8.0.0/24          to:120.xx.xx.xx
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      wlan0   10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0
   22  1386            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fe80::6f08:6434:23ed:1239  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1173  bytes 75296 (75.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 432 (432.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.188  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        ether 02:81:05:ba:1b:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 62966  bytes 75908690 (75.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1012  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18570  bytes 2387345 (2.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Also, `sysctl -a` shows `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.

Update: Some more output

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Here's the `ovpn`:

```
client
proto udp
remote 120.xx.xx.xx 443
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_EjfYsD2SU86zv2oB name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
...
```

UPDATE2: After adding a few rules to iptables, clients still can't access the internet:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -v --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere
3     1094  134K ACCEPT     udp  --  wlan0  any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443
4      721  721K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
8        1   201 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2      417 26066 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  tun0    anywhere             anywhere
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   wlan0   anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 496 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost none of your `iptables` rules has any effect - other than counting packets - because the default policy is `ACCEPT`. The exception is your `POSTROUTING` table, which manages to mangle the packets irretrievably.

You need to define what services you want to expose to the Internet (assuming your 120.x.x.x is Internet reachable), and block everything else. This example allows udp/443, tcp/22 and icmp:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT    # Existing connections
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT                      # OpenVPN
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT                       # SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT                                 # Ping and other ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT                                         # Discard everything else

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE               # Hide behind me
```

There are more sophisticated examples available (just search with terms like "openvpn iptables masquerade") but this should be a minimum to get you running.

Comment: Thanks. I've done as you suggested but unfortunately there's still no access. Please see the updated iptables.

Comment: I've fixed it by removing the SNAT rule. Thanks for the rules you suggested though!

Comment: @JohnM that means your server is connected to the Internet and completely unprotected.

Comment: Well, I only had 443 port forwarded though.

Comment: You've got every port accessible. Run `netstat -na | grep LISTEN` to see what can be attacked.

Comment: But if I only had 443 port forwarded and my VPN server was on 443, then attackers wouldn't be able to penetrate into my other services, right?